# Is it possible to serialize the SparkContext in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, serialization

I would like to save SparkContext state periodically and I was wondering whether it is possible to serialize the SparkContext class. I looked into using a Scala pickler but that involves writing a custom pickler. I was wondering whether an easier approach is available.

Comment: What are you trying to serialize exactly ? The spark context holds information about the state of the spark runtime and allows to launch jobs, essentially. I don't think whatever you're trying to persist could even be contained in the spark context.

Comment: I am trying to replicate SparkContext such that if the driver program goes down, I can start a new machine with the previously saved (serialized) state of the SparkContext and load up the new SparkContext with the same state. This way I don't lose the state of the job and I don't have to restart.